# How to use Python 3.5 as default python interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, macos-sierra

I just installed Python 3.5 on my Mac OS Sierra and update my .bash_profile file:

```
MacBook:~ admin$ more .bash_profile

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When I check if the PATH is correctly set, I have the below output:

```
MacBook:~ admin$ echo "$PATH"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet
```

However, when I run Python from a terminal, Python 2.7 is still executed:

```
MacBook:~ admin$ python --version Python 2.7.12
MacBook:~ admin$ which python /usr/local/bin/python
```

How can I use Python 3.5 by default?

Comment: I would advise against doing this.  Make a symlink for python3, and leave the system default version alone.

Comment: It's just one more character to type `python3`

Comment: Use virtualenv or something like that, so you don't mess with the default interpreter (you may even break your system if some tools depend on 2.7).

Comment: I double @PauloScardine . I'd rather install a virtualenv with Python 3.5 and make it load automatically when firing a terminal session

Comment: From experience don't do that. Did a similar thing on mac with Ruby ended up rolling back the whole machine with the time machine backup. If you do at least name it to something else then python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your surprise comes from the shell searching /usr/bin before it tries your PATH.  You really do *not* want to mess with that part, but you can work around it with a simple alias.  Something like

```
alias python='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python'
```

... should do the trick.  However, I recommend that you choose a name other than **python**, such as **pyth** or **py3**.

Comment: ... which is handled in a previous comment.

Comment: True. But I think most popular *nix environments already come with a `python3`, usually pointing to a python 3.4 interpreter. It's been a while since I've used Mac OS, although, I might be returning to it soon.